# how do I make table from arry DATA

Tags: javascript, excel, text, printing, datatable

How do I print loaded DATA from text file in this form to a table

```
['1','apple','banana','1'],

['2','joystick','game','1'],

['3','help','me','1'],

1 apple banana 1

2 joystick game 1

3 help me 1
```

and for example only

```
apple banana

joystick game
```

help me

Comment: What table are you referring to? Please add this to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<table>'+data.map(row=>'<tr>'+row.map(cell=>'<td>'+cell+'</td>').join('')+'</tr>').join('')+'</table>';
```